Handle date object in API response
I have a c# .net 8 backend (later known as BE) to provide my react typescript frontend (FE) with data.
I use RTK Query to fetch the data but I just ran into trouble when assuming that the Date object I got from BE was infact a Date object.
Class in BE:
public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}

Type in FE:
export interface Action {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
}

RTK Query endpoint:
actionById: builder.query<Action, number>({
   query: (id: number) => ({
       url: `${BASE_URL}/v1/Action/${id}`
       method: 'GET',
   }),
}),

Response from BE is obiviously a JSON String but I thought the conversion to Date object were made automatically. It was not.
Everything worked fine until I tried to compare it with another date which failed.
So question is, how do I solve this in the best way?
I could change the type in FE to be startDate: string; to avoid the confusion, but is there a better way?

You could write some http interceptor or handle in the response obj,startDate = new Date(response.startDate)

I would suggest to use transformResponse in order to transform response data as needed. Maybe something like this:
actionById: builder.query<Action, number>({
  query: (id: number) => `${BASE_URL}/v1/Action/${id}`,
  transformResponse: (response) => ({ ...response, startDate: new Date(response.startDate) }),
}),

